# Best way to store test data in WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to know which is the best way to store test data in WebDriver automation? XML or Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Anything that fits your test model and environment, is reliable and works for you. 
If it's file based, make sure you have a reliable format. 
Personally I would recommend JSON or YAML. 
It's super flexible and portable and a lot easier to parse than most. 
There are lots of file based formats. 
You could also use SQLite. It's a small reliable and portable format.

You could also use remote data in any kind of database. 
NoSQL databases can be well suited for this. 
Many offer REST APIs also.